# Is it possible to have the same effect of the ALT F2 like Gnome Shell

Tags: customization, lubuntu

I was trying Gnome Shell (in openSuse) and found out that when I do the old ALT + F2 and the old execute command is now a small black space to complete... I want that on Lubuntu.

Somebody know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many standalone launchers. I think lxde comes with a <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run command. If you would like to have a look in something else, there are:

`gmrun`

`grun`

[bashrun](http://code.google.com/p/bashrun2/)

If you want something more than just a run dialog, have a look at

`gnome-do`

`synapse`

`kupfer`

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu uses LXDE, which is a different desktop environment than Gnome. However, anything that can be installed in Ubuntu can be installed in Lubuntu, and Ubuntu now uses Gnome 3 by default.

In other words; it is not possible to get the same Alt+F2 dialog in LXDE as you have in Gnome Shell, but it is possible to install Gnome Shell and use it in Lubuntu, as long as you are using Lubuntu 11.10.

First, install [Gnome Shell](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-shell). It is likely to require a little time to download since it has requirements not shared with LXDE. When it's finished installing, you can choose Gnome from the session menu before you log in.

Comment: ok I understand that but I'm only wanted that small efect. It's that too much to lubunut?

Comment: If you want just a launcher see `gmrun` or http://code.google.com/p/bashrun2/ but for exactly gnome-shell like dialog you will need gnome-shell

Comment: @sagarchalise was the one who gave me an answer that I can actually use. but I can select his coment to be the correct answer.